# how to create bean object of Boolean class

Tags: java, boolean, javabeans

I declare a bean like this,

```
<bean id="booleabBeab" class="java.lang.Boolean" init-method="booleanValue()"></bean>
```

but I am getting an error at

```
ApplicationContext spring = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configFileName);
```

The error is:

> Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Boolean]: No default constructor found; nested exception is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`: `java.lang.Boolean.<init>()`

Answer (score 6):

Boolean does not have any no-argument constructor. so you need to pass constructor argument like

```
<bean id="booleabBeab" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write your own class which contains a `boolean` field and appropriate getters and setters. `Boolean` cannot be used as a bean because it does not have a default constructor and also because it has no setter.